# How to delete folders which do not have a name "xyz" with Windows batch script

Tags: windows

I have a folder `C:\remote` which has two folders each, A and B. Each of those contain mutiple folders inside it, for example `xyc`, `dsx`, `axyz`, and so on. I want to delete any subfolder which does not have a name `xyz`.

I have the following script:

```
set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks" 
cd /d %folder% 
for /F "delims<>" %%i in ('migrate') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

I wanted to delete all folders which are not named as `migrate`.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not very clear. Also, please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Here is my script whoch wont work I wanted to delete all folder which are not named as migrate

Comment: set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims<>" %%i in ('migrate') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Do you want to delete all folders **that  contain the string "migrate"**? or **does not contain the string "migrate"**?

Comment: Delete all folder which does not contain string "migrate"

Comment: So why does your current script do the complete opposite?

Comment: @ramhound I think the OP is completely confused about how `for /f` works (his command is broken) , which is understandable as it is quite complex to get it right. Anyway, I've answered his question as best as it can be understood.

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to delete all folders that do not contain the string migrate

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks" 
cd /d %folder% 
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /a:d /b /s ^| findstr /v /i migrate` ) do (
  echo rd /s /q %%i
)
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Remove the `echo` when you are happy with what the batch file will do.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [rd](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) - Delete folder(s).